# A simple question about free group

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-groups

Fix $r\in \mathbb{N}$ and let $\mathbb{F}_{r}=\langle g_{1}, ...,g_{r}\rangle$ be the rank-r free group.

I have asked a question several days ago: Is $\mathbb{F}_{2}$ a subgroup of $\mathbb{F}_{3}$? But, I find a statment in a book "$\mathbb{F}_{3}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{F}_{2}$". Could some one explain to me which is correct? Why? (Or recommend me a reference) Many thanks.

Comment: They are both correct; presumably you'll receive a proof of the second statement soon.

Comment: Ah? Both correct?

Comment: check here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628637/prove-elements-generate-a-free-group/637753#637753 to see how is the proof of "$F_3$ has an isomorphic copy in $F_2$"

Comment: @janmarqz Thanks for your comment. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The free group $F_2$ is the group whose elements are all the "words" formed by 2 "letters" $a$ and $b$ together with their inverses and the empty word which acts as neutral element. So
$$
F_2=\{\emptyset,a,b,a^\prime,b^\prime,aa,ab,ba,bb,ab^\prime,...\}
$$
(A prime denotes inverse).

Now the idea is simply that if you take 3 different non-trivial words $p$, $q$, $r\in F_2$ with no relation among them (say you need to avoid things like $r=pq$ and so on), then the subgroup of $F_2$ that they generate is actually isomorphic to $F_3$ (think of them as letters, and you're forming all words with $p$, $q$ and $r$)

Along the same idea, you can actually construct a subgroup of $F_2$ isomorphic to $F_n$, whatever $n>0$.

Comment: But how to choose the non-trivial words $p, q, r$ with no relation? Could you give me a concrete triple expressed by $a, b$?

Comment: Well, tale for intance $aa$, $ab$ and $baba$. That should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Mori.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, **every** subgroup of $\mathbb{F}_2$ is isomorphic to one of $\mathbb{F}_n$ for $n\in \{0,1,2,\dots,n,\dots\aleph_0\}$ and every $\mathbb{F}_n$ is attained thereby. (Here $\mathbb{F}_{\aleph_0}$ is the free group of countably infinite rank and $\mathbb{F}_0$ the trivial group.)